# Is there a way to remove firstChild of an element other than using table.innetHTML = " " when calling a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a student arry
`const students = []`

and i have `addEventListener`

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  const student = {
    name: this.name.value,
  };

  students.push(student);

   this.reset();

  renderStudents();
});
```

I have this render students function that i called in the `addEventListener`

```
function renderStudents() {

  students.forEach((student) => {

    const tr = document.createElement("tr");

    const tdName = document.createElement("td");
    tdname.innerText = student.name;

    tr.append(
      tdName,
    );

    table.appendChild(tr);
  });
```

When i add one student it will display in the table, but when i try to add another student, the previous students gets also added to the table again.

I could solve that by adding `table.innerHTML = ""` to the `renderStudents()` function at the start, is there any other way to solve that?
Because it feels like this would give other errors

Comment: You can use `element.firstChild.remove()`.

Comment: Because you are rendering the entire array of elements again and NOT the one you just added!

Comment: Maybe you could initiate the table in your function `renderStudents()`, that way, each time you call the function, you create a new (empty) table. You could also replace the first child with a new one by using the function `element.replaceChild`. Tell me if this helps :)

Comment: `firstElementChild` may be safer than `firstChild`. If you use `appendChild()`, finding `removeChild()` on the same [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) should not be that challenging.

Comment: Tose suggestioning removal.... what happens when there is 2 and 3. There is ZERO REASON to remove.

Comment: The OP should refactor the code in a way that there is a single `renderStudent` function which does everything the anonymous arrow function expression within `student.forEach` is doing. The `renderStudents` function then could be renamed to `renderAllStudents` and be implemented like `students.forEach(renderStudent);`. The latter then needs to be invoked just for the initial rendering of all `students`, whereas the former gets invoked within the `submit` handler ... thus the handler function's last line should change from `renderStudents();` to `renderStudent(student);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you issue is with the `students` Array.

You should avoid to use this global variable and just pass the Array to the `renderStudents()` function.

So like this:

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  const student = {
    name: this.name.value,
  };

  this.reset();

  renderStudents([ student ]); // Pass the Array to the function
});


function renderStudents(students) {

  students.forEach((student) => {

    const tr = document.createElement("tr");

    const tdName = document.createElement("td");
    tdname.innerText = student.name;

    tr.append(
      tdName,
    );

    table.appendChild(tr);
  });
```

You can other stratiegies and use the *global* `students` Array to have your model with all the students inside, and just check on your code there are not duplication on the list.

Then you create all the rows on each add, after you removed all the existing one from the DOM.

Or you can to filter the `students` Array getting only the students that need to be added checking what already present.

This will be a problem when your table will get a lot of records.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add what you are setting, there is no reason to loop over the array. Change your code to use what you need to add.

```js
const table = document.querySelector("#t tbody");

function renderStudents(additionalStudents) {

  additionalStudents.forEach((student) => {

    const tr = document.createElement("tr");

    const tdName = document.createElement("td");
    tdName.innerText = student.name;

    tr.append(tdName);

    table.appendChild(tr);
  });
}

var students = [{
  name: 'a'
}];
renderStudents(students);

var newStudent = {
  name: 'b'
};
students.push(newStudent);
renderStudents([newStudent]);
```

```html
<table id="t">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So your code would be

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  const student = {
    name: this.name.value,
  };

  students.push(student);

   this.reset();

  renderStudents([student]);
});

function renderStudents(additionalStudents) {

  additionalStudents.forEach((student) => {

    const tr = document.createElement("tr");

    const tdName = document.createElement("td");
    tdname.innerText = student.name;

    tr.append(
      tdName,
    );

    table.appendChild(tr);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another array (`const studentsRendered = []`) to track the already rendered elements. Then in your event handler check `if (!studentsRendered.includes(student))` and render the student and add it to `studentsRendered`. This way only the newly added student will be added to the table.
Here is an example with pre-loaded data in the `students` array:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form')
const table = document.querySelector('#table')
const studentsRendered = []
const students = [{
  name: 'pre-loaded name'
}]

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const student = {
    name: this.name.value,
  };
  students.push(student);
  this.reset();
  renderStudents();
});

function renderStudents() {
  students.forEach((student) => {
    if (!studentsRendered.includes(student)) {
      const tr = document.createElement("tr");
      const tdName = document.createElement("td");
      tdName.innerText = student.name;
      tr.append(
        tdName,
      );
      table.appendChild(tr);
      studentsRendered.push(student)
    }
  });
  console.log(studentsRendered)
}
renderStudents()
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="name">Student Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button>
    add
  </button>
</form>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there a actually serveral ways to solve this, and using `while()` is one of them.

Now what you could do is simply add a while lopp in the `renderStudents()` function, but NOTE that you will have to add it at the start, like this:

```
   function renderStudents() {

    while(table.firstChild){ 
        table.removeChild(table.firstChild) // this will remove the firstChild of the element
    }

  students.forEach((student) => {

    const tr = document.createElement("tr");

    const tdName = document.createElement("td");
    tdName.innerText = student.name;

    tr.append(
      tdName
    );

    table.appendChild(tr);
  });
}
```

What this will do is that it will remove the first child everytime we call the `renderStudent()` function.